# Scroll position of RecyclerView lost when returning back to activity from another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I m using Firebase `RecyclerView.Apdapter` with Firebase UI in MainActivity.
When I'm opening another activity and returning back to main activity, scroll position moves to top. How to have same scroll position after closing of other activity using Firebase RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to know that the component responsible one for holding the `layout state` (and restoring it) is the `LayoutManager` used in your `RecyclerView`. To achieve this, you can override the `onSaveInstanceState()` method and store the position directly in the `Bundle` object.

To get it back, just override the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method and get the position back fron the `Bundle` object.

In the end just simply use the following line of code in your `onStart()` method:

```
layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(yourListState);
```